# MVC Dropdown using ViewModels without Magic String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to get a drop-down from a database to work. I did not get too far. I am trying to do it using viewModel and not use Magic String. I have a feeling I am not too far off. Could some please take a look and see what I am missing or doing wrong?

I am getting a compiling error at this line in the controller: viewModel.Courts = CourtList,

I am pretty sure it is wrong but I am running of ideas on how to do this.

Domain Models:

```
 public class Parent
{

    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual Court Court { get; set; }
    //public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Courts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set; }

}

 public class Court
{
    public int CourtId { get; set; }
    public string CourtName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class ParentVM
{

    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    //public int CourtId { get; set; }
    //public string CourtName { get; set; }

    public virtual Court Court { get; set; }
    //public virtual IEnumerable<Court> CourtList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Courts { get; set; }

    public IList<ChildVM> Children { get; set; } 

}
```

Controller:

```
// GET: Parents/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CourtList = db.Courts.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.CourtId.ToString(),
            Text = x.CourtName,

        });



        //ViewBag.CourtList = new SelectList(db.Courts, "CourtId", "CourtName");

        ParentVM viewModel = new ParentVM()
        {
            Children = new List<ChildVM>()
            {
                new ChildVM(){Name="", DOB="", Address=""},
                //new ChildVM(){Name="2", DOB="2", Address="222"},
                //new ChildVM(){Name="3", DOB="3", Address="3"},                    
            },

            viewModel.Courts = CourtList,
        };

        return View(viewModel);

    }

    // POST: Parents/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ParentVM viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var parent = new Parent()
            {
                FirstName = viewModel.FirstName,
                LastName = viewModel.LastName
            };

            db.Parents.Add(parent);

            foreach (ChildVM item in viewModel.Children)
            {

                var child = new Child()
                {
                    Name = item.Name,
                    DOB = item.DOB,
                    Address = item.Address
                };

                db.Childs.Add(child);
            }

            //Parent parent = new Parent();              
            //var employee = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Parent, ParentVM>(parent);                        

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Courts", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.Courts)
```

Comment: You cant use the same name for the property and the collection. Your view model needs a property to bind to e.g. `public int SelectedCourt { get; set; }` and then `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCourt, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.Courts)`. You also need to reassign `Courts` when you return the view in the POST method

Comment: OK, I added the SelectedCourt property to the view model and change the drop down. I changed viewModel.Courts = CourtList, to viewModel.SelectedCourt = CourtList, in the controller. I am still getting compiler errors.

Comment: No, `SelectedCourt` needs to be `int` and it still needs to be `viewModel.Courts = CourtList`. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trying to bind you dropdownlist to property `Courts` which is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. A `<select>` posts back a value type (the value of the selected item) which cannot be bound to a collection. You need an additional property to bind to (or you could bind to `Court.CourtId`, but the `CourtName` property of `Court` wont be bound on postback.

View model

```
public class ParentVM
{
  public int ParentID { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public int? SelectedCourt { get; set; } // bind the dropdown to this
  public SelectList CourtList { get; set; }
  public IList<ChildVM> Children { get; set; } 
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  ParentVM model = new ParentVM()
  {
    Children = new List<ChildVM>() .....,
    CourtList = new SelectList(db.Courts, "CourtId", "CourtName"),
    SelectCourt = // set a value here if you want a specific option to be selected
  });
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ParentVM model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    Court court = db.Courts.Find(model.SelectedCourt) // get the Court based on `SelectedCourt`
    var parent = new Parent()
    {
      FirstName = model.FirstName,
      LastName = model.LastName,
      Court  = court
    };
    db.Parents.Add(parent);
    foreach (ChildVM item in viewModel.Children)
    {
      ....
      db.Childs.Add(child);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  model.CourtList = new SelectList(db.Courts, "CourtId", "CourtName"); // reassign select list
  return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCourt, Model.CourtList, "--Please select--")
```

If the value of `SelectedCourt` matches the value of one of the options, it will be selected when the page is rendered, otherwise the first (label) option will be selected. When you post back, the value of `SelectedCourt` will be the value of the selected option

Comment: Ok, it worked great. But now I am trying to do the Edit Get() and Post() without any luck. Should I mark this as answered and create a brand new question?

Comment: Best to ask a new question if your have issues with it. But your get method should be something like `Edit(int ID)` and then your get the `Parent` object from the db and map its properties to `ParentVM` - otherwise it wont be much different from your create methods

Comment: Wait, I am not understanding something here. Do I need to add the SelectedCourt  property to the Parent model as well? Because when I postback on my create and click the edit view it does not retain its value.

Comment: No. its belongs in the view model only (so you can get the selected `Court`) In your create method, when you save, you need to get the `Court` from the database based on the value of `SelectedCourt` and then assign that to the data model before you save `Parent`

Comment: I still do not understand. I get the concept of creating a list id and value for the dropdown from a table. But once I create and save, what do I save in parent model? There is no property to save? IN your answer you did not specify to add a property there. I would guess I would save the id portion (of dropdown) so when I click on edit view it retain it value. I checked the Parent table and it has a Court_CourtId column. I am guessing I need to save the Id from the dropdown to that column but I am not understanding how.

Comment: You `Parent` class has `public virtual Court Court { get; set; }` so you should be able to set that when your saving. I will update my answer shortly with what I think you need (I don't use EF so can't be sure)

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I figure out how to do the Get Edit() now I need help the post. I will create a new question. I am sure it is very basic.

Comment: I probably should have said `db.Courts.Where(c => c.CourtId == model.SelectedCourt).FirstOrDefault();` - but looks like you have got the idea :)

Comment: Yes, I am having issue with the Post Edit(), would you mind checking this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596718/mvc-dropdown-postback-issue?noredirect=1#comment43617228_27596718