# MVC dropdown postback issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is a continuation of a previous questions.

[MVC Dropdown using ViewModels without Magic String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595715/mvc-dropdown-using-viewmodels-without-magic-string/27595950#27595950)

With the help of Stephen, I manage to make the Create methods work, now I need help with the Edit methods.

I manage to get the Get Edit () method going but when I post back it does not save the new value of the dropdown. I use the debugger and I could not see why. It looked like it was doing what it was suppose to.

```
// GET: Parents/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Parent parent = db.Parents.Find(id);

        if (parent == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        ParentVM viewModel = new ParentVM()
        {
            CourtList = new SelectList(db.Courts, "CourtId", "CourtName"),
            SelectedCourt = parent.Court.CourtId,
            ParentID = parent.ParentID,
            FirstName = parent.FirstName,
            LastName = parent.LastName,
            Children = parent.Childs.Select(c => new ChildVM()
            {
                ChildID = c.ChildID,
                ParentID = c.ParentID,
                Name = c.Name,
                DOB = c.DOB,
                Address = c.Address
            }).ToList(),

        };

        return View(viewModel);

    }

    // POST: Parents/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(ParentVM viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            Court court = db.Courts.Find(viewModel.SelectedCourt);
            var parent = new Parent()
            {
                FirstName = viewModel.FirstName,
                LastName = viewModel.LastName,
                ParentID = viewModel.ParentID,
                Court = court

            };

            db.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;

            foreach (ChildVM item in viewModel.Children)
            {

                var child = new Child()
                {
                    Name = item.Name,
                    DOB = item.DOB,
                    Address = item.Address,
                    ParentID = viewModel.ParentID,
                    ChildID = item.ChildID
                };


                db.Entry(child).State = child.ChildID == 0 ?
                               EntityState.Added :
                               EntityState.Modified;

            }



            var findChild = db.Childs.Where(x => x.ParentID == viewModel.ParentID).ToList();

            foreach (var item in findChild)
            {

                var deleteChild = viewModel.Children.Where(x => x.ChildID == item.ChildID).SingleOrDefault();

                if (deleteChild == null)
                {
                    db.Childs.Remove(item);
                }

            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        viewModel.CourtList = new SelectList(db.Courts, "CourtId", "CourtName");
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: You need another method to handle the post. That one is a get.

Comment: They are both there, you need to scroll down.

Comment: put a break point at db.SaveChanges(); and check it is being hit. If yes watch db.Courts at this moment and check if it holds the updated values

Comment: Is `Court court = db.Courts.Find(viewModel.SelectedCourt);` reurning a valid object?

Comment: yes it returns an object. I create a new record save it. Then I open (edit) I modify the drop down to a new value and save. I re-open the record and it keep the original drop down value.

Comment: Why create a new `Parent` - as opposed to getting the existing parent based on `ParentId` and updating its properties?

Comment: Honestly, I do not know. I thought you help me with that 3 weeks ago and that is what we ended up with. I do not understand that it works fine on the Create postback but not the edit postback. According to the debugger it retains the new id from the dropdown until I save the changes to the db.

Comment: EF is not my thing, but I suspect you need to attach the entity before saving `db.Entry.Attach(parent); db.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Modified; ... db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Is there a value in court? Court court = db.Courts.Find(viewModel.SelectedCourt);

Comment: Yes, there is a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try out this code. If you have any questions just ask. 
Check out my comments inside the code.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ParentVM viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Court court = db.Courts.Find(viewModel.SelectedCourt);
        var parent = db.Parents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ParentID == viewModel.ParentID);
        if (parent != null)
        {
            // Parent exists in DB --> You can just update it
            parent.FirstName = viewModel.FirstName;
            parent.LastName = view;
            Model.LastName;
            parent.ParentID = viewModel.ParentID;
            parent.Court = court;
        }
        else
        {
            // Parent does not exist in DB --> You have to Add a new Parent
            db.Parents.Add(new Parent()
            {
                FirstName = viewModel.FirstName,
                LastName = viewModel.LastName,
                ParentID = viewModel.ParentID,
                Court = court
            });
        }

        foreach (ChildVM item in viewModel.Children)
        {
             // Here you can do exactly the same like you did bevore with your Parents
             // First search for your Child in DB
             var child = db.Childs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ChildID == item.ChildID);
             if (child != null)
             {
                 child.Name = item.Name;
                 child.DOB = item.DOB;
                 child.Address = item.Address;
                 child.ParentID = viewModel.ParentID;
                 child.ChildID = item.ChildID;
             }
             else
             {
                 db.Childs.Add(new Child()
                 {
                     Name = item.Name,
                     DOB = item.DOB,
                     Address = item.Address,
                     ParentID = viewModel.ParentID,
                     ChildID = item.ChildID
                 });
             }
         }

         // Here I don't get what you want to do...
         // Can you explain me that?
         var findChild = db.Childs.Where(x => x.ParentID == viewModel.ParentID).ToList();

         foreach (var item in findChild)
         {
             var deleteChild = viewModel.Children.Where(x => x.ChildID == item.ChildID).SingleOrDefault();

             if (deleteChild == null)
             {
                 db.Childs.Remove(item);
             }
          }

          db.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }

     viewModel.CourtList = new SelectList(db.Courts, "CourtId", "CourtName");
     return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just used your code and I get the following error: not all code paths return a value. It highlight the Edit of this line:public ActionResult Edit(ParentVM viewModel)  I also fix the typo you had with the LastName.

Comment: Also, the last bit, were you ask what it does. That is my code when I remove the child documents. I have jquery code that add or remove rows. Now I want to delete the rows in the database as well, if I need to.

Comment: @Hockey_Fan please check out my updated code. I don't know if your code for removing your childs will work but give it a try

Comment: It works great. I can modify the dropdown and it retains the value. I can also add / remove child and the tables are update accordingly. Thank so much. You changed the logic I had for my Edit postback. I am wondering now should I change the logic for the Create postback? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595715/mvc-dropdown-using-viewmodels-without-magic-string/27595950#27595950

Comment: Yeah if you have both methods (Create and Edit), you have dublicated code i think. 
I would recomend you to rename my method (Edit) to "SaveParentVM" or something like that and then you can just call this methode and it does not depend wheter you edit an existing ParentVM or wheter you are creating a new ParentVM.

Comment: I just want to say thank you to you both Stephen and brothers28. You two helped me tremendously. Have a great day!

Comment: @Hockey_Fan no problem meen. You too and merry christmas ;)